# In Magento 2 how can i change url of color filter layer navigation?

Tags: php, magento2

On category page after click in color attribute I am getting below URL

```
123.456.78.960:8080/projects/mg_magento2/code3/demo?filtercolor=213
```

in above URL I want to change `filtercolor=red` instead of `filtercolor=213` .

I want This type of URL : `123.456.78.960:8080/projects/mg_magento2/code3/demo?filtercolor=red`

so in sort I want to set color name instead of color code. so can anyone help me to resolve this issue In magento 2.

Please check screen shot for your reference. 
[image]

Comment: thanks @manashvi birla

Answer (score 1):

Their is written module to solve this issue.

https://github.com/jruzafa/Devopensource_LayerCatSeo

Download it from github and install to your magento website.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want solution in magento 2 not in magneto community.